# People using genetic engineering to transform their offspring to live on a gaseous planet

Tags: story-identification, genetic-engineering, generation-ship

I was hoping for some help. I remember parts of a science fiction plot point and I’m trying to locate the story. I’m not sure if it is a short story, a novel, or even an extremely short lived science fiction anthology show.

Here is what I remember. It was at least 15 years ago probably longer.

- A generation ship or something like it is stranded.
- The colonists or scientists stuck on the ship can’t get to their final destination, so they must make do in the local area. There are no human friendly habitable planets (at least as we are,) but they can genetically engineer their offspring to live on the planet they are near. Not over many generations but quickly.
- This might be a gaseous planet. Their altered kids do well on the planet and have trouble understanding their parents’ anguish that they are no longer human (at least genetically.) The kids are not humanoid. I’m hazy on it but they look more like something that can float in a gaseous environment. The end is somewhat poignant as kids are fine as they are and wonder why their parents seem so sad.

Does this ring any bells? I thought it might be part of Ben Bova’s *Exiles Trilogy* but I was wrong on that on score. James Blish’s novel *Surface Tension*, Simak’s *Desertion* and Budrys’ *Between the Dark and the Daylight* are in the ballpark but not the story I’m looking for as I haven’t read them, but they sound similar. I’m hoping someone else might have ideas.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please review this checklist we've developed for story IDs and [edit] your post with any additional details you remember from that checklist (e.g. when did you read this)?

Comment: Blish wrote other stories besides "Surface Tension" that dealt with the theme of modifying humans for exotic environments. They were collected into a fixup novel called "The Seedling Stars". I haven't read it, so I don't know if your story is part of it.